# Python convert txt file to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, text, converters

I was wondering what would be simplest way to convert txt files in path batch convert to PDF?

I've looked into this in Python https://github.com/baruchel/txt2pdf
but I can't seem to call txt2pdf in terminal after importing it.

Any other suggestions?

Something like:

```
text_file = open(filename, 'r')
i = 0
for item in text_file:
    i += 1
    f = open("c:\\workspace\\{0}.txt".format(i), 'w')
    txt2pdf convert (whatever goes here)
        if i == 7:
           break
```

also tried this using ReportLab

```
def hello(c):
ic = 0
c = open("c:\\workspace\\simple\\{0}.txt".format(ic), 'w')
for item in c:
    ic += 1
    c = canvas.Canvas("c:\\workspace\\simple\\{0}.pdf".format(ic))
    hello(c)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    if ic == 7:
        break
```

Comment: Where is your `text2pdf.py` located?

Answer (score 3):

Go here to see how [click this](https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/convert-text-to-html-docx-and-pdf/)

This is the code after you installed pdfkit as the post of the link above shows

```
# from txt to html
# install wkthtml
import os
import pdfkit

with open("text.txt") as file:
    with open ("text.html", "w") as output:
        file = file.read()
        file = file.replace("\n", "<br>")
        output.write(file)

pdfkit.from_file("text.html", "output.pdf")

os.startfile("output.pdf")
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure you already found the solution or not, just happen to see this question when I also searching the answer for related to your question.

You can just run as below if you are in terminal:

```
python txt2pdf.py yourfile.txt 
## Make sure the txt2pdf.py is at your working environment and also the .txt too
```

Or if you run in jupyter notebook, just run as below:

```
run txt2pdf.py yourfile.txt
```

Thank you.